# ¿Como Evitar Ingeniería Inversa en C#?

Tags: c#, seguridad, telerik

hace tiempo cree un Ejecutable (*.exe*) con *InstallShield* y *Visual Studio 2015* usando como lenguaje de programación **C#**.

Pero encontré un programa llamado [TELERIK](http://www.telerik.com/), con el cual es posible a partir del .exe generado obtener el código fuente, Hice pruebas y efectivamente me muestra mi código tal cual lo escribí.

¿Como proteger mi código Fuente?

Comment: Ofuscación del código es un inicio. Aunque no conozco del tema, cuando se trata de ingeniería inversa y seguridad hay otras medidas. Puede ser que tu pregunta sea reportada como `se basa principalmente en opiniones`.

Comment: Tu titulo no es el adecuado, ingeniería inversa se llama cuando tienes una base de datos y puedes obtener un modelo lógico con alguna herramienta case.

Comment: No precisamente en una base de datos, te falta googlearlo @PedroÁvila

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Actualización:**

Puedes Ofuscar las dll, .exe, etc. de aplicación .Net, con esto se protege contra ingeniería inversa.

Para esto puedes utilizar alguna aplicación como esta:

[Babel Obfuscation](http://babelfor.net/)

---

Creo que el problema reside al crear el `.exe`, debes crearlo con la opción `RELEASE` y no `DEBUG`

Hablando de **Telerik** es la empresa no es un programa, **Telerik** tiene muchas herramientas.

Igual manera **JetBrains(Resharper)** tiene una herramienta que hace lo mismo

[Herramienta de JetBrains-Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

**dotPeek**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Herramienta de Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

**JustDecompile**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tus comentarios, espero algun dia ir a Culiacan

Comment: Seras bienvenido  :-)  Saludos

Answer (score 3):

No puedes evitar la ingeniería inversa mientras tengan acceso al ejecutable,  sus componentes como dlls y aun software de desensamblado, con esto podrán generar código fuente a partir de tu código compilado y el resultado no será 100% exacto a como lo programaste, como menciona Mauricio en su respuesta puedes ofuscar el código para hacer mas bajo el % de precisión de código generado por la ingeniería inversa o hacer el proceso de ingeniería inversa mas difícil.

Nota: Ofuscar tampoco te protege al 100% y aunque lo pongas en opcion RELEASE lo unico que genera es que el codigo compilado contenga menos metadatos que son usados durante el proceso de ingenieria inversa para generar una version mas parecida al codigo original. La razon es que C# compila sobre CLI a diferencia de codigo maquina optimizado como C o C++ y por esta razon los ejecutables contienen muchos metadatos que guardan informacion sobre el codigo fuente original

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tus comentarios, ha sido de gran ayuda